# How to handle deleted app device token in Pushwoosh?

Tags: java, android, ios, push-notification, pushwoosh

I am using [**Pushwoosh**](https://www.pushwoosh.com/) for sending notifications to **Android** and **iOS** apps from **Java** Webservices. I found it very easy to use.

I have successfully implemented it. I am using [**createMessage**](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/#PushserviceAPI-Method-messages-create) method with multiple device tokens for sending notifications.

I have used it for many times, and was getting proper response. But after some time I'm getting some device tokens in **UnknownDevices** key in a response. It is because some devices have deleted the app.

So is there any way that I can handle this situation that not sending notifications to devices which have deleted the app? How can I know that device has deleted the app?

Does **Pushwoosh** blocks account if I keep sending notifications to devices which has deleted the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of handling this:

1. Send pushes via Tags feature, where you set Tags on the device with the [setTags method](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/#PushserviceAPI-MethodSetTags), not with push tokens. We will remove invalid/expired tokens for you.
2. You can use getUnregisteredDevices method, which is currently not documented publicly, but the [Support team](https://www.pushwoosh.com/contact-us/) can provide details. the only disadvantage of this method is that it does not return iOS tokens handled by Apple feedback Service.

Comment: Thanks, but does Pushwoosh blocks my account if I keep sending notifications to devices which has deleted the app?

Comment: Hi, no, Pushwoosh won't block your account for this as long as you don't abuse the API.